# ajax button press value not being pulled out

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call from a button press that posts the value of the button, I intend to have multiple choice buttons to press.

Here is the script that posts the value to /_url

```
$(function() {
  $('a#buttonpress').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/_url', {
      a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").text(data.result);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" size="5" name="a"> 
    <p><a href="javascript:void();" id="buttonpress">Submit</a>
</form>
```

This works fine as an input field but when I try do it straight from a button click, it doesn't work, here is want I want and have...

```
<button type="submit" a href="javascript:void();" 
id="buttonpress" value="aValue">Submit</button>
```

Can anyone help me to pull the value out of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just do this

```
<button type="submit" a href="javascript:void();" 
id="buttonpress" value="aValue">Submit</button>
```

First of all, `href` is not a valid attribute of button tag. And second of all, you're using `a` also, which means you add an empty tag named `a`. This is why selector `a#buttonpress` doesn't work, because there's no `<a ...>` tag in your html.

You can do this:

```
<button type="submit" id="buttonpress" value="aValue">Submit</button>
```

And for javascript:

```
var buttonValue = $('#buttonpress').val();
```

And also, you're using [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) wrong, correct way is:

```
$.getJSON('url', { data })
    .done(function(data) { ... })
    // Other handlers (.fail, .always)
```

When you click submit inside a `form`, browser will automatically attempt to submit the values to form's `action` url, if it's defined.

To put it all together:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        $.getJSON('/_url', {
            a: $('#buttonpress').val()
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // This is important, it assures that form won't be sent
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added your changes but that doesn't appear to be working either

Comment: My code should work correctly. If you copy `$('input[name="a"]').val()` in developer console, you should see the value of input field printed out. You'll have to be more specific on why it doesn't work, but there's either an error somewhere else in your code or something with the server.

Comment: Think I'm confused as to which to use for the button press?

Comment: the posted back value is just coming back as NULL

Comment: How is this part of your script still valid for the button press? a: $('input[name="a"]').val()

Comment: You have an input named `a` (`<input ... name="a">`), don't you? I don't see anything wrong with the selector, try it out yourself. The problem was, which I haven't even noticed at first, you're using `getJSON` and your usage is wrong. I've edited question *again* to explain what's wrong and updated solution.

Comment: I dont want to use a form input field just a button press, The input field was just to show what I had working i.e. a user entering text and a value the being returned. What I actually want is a predefined value in a button not in input field

Comment: Next time make yourself more clear. Use `$('#buttonpress').val()` then. And next time, you can try and see for yourself, not ask someone else to narrate you each and every character of the code *you* are writing. Learn by trial and error, you'll get the most out of it. And it's not like you'll break anything if it doesn't work the first time.

Comment: Thanks that's done the trick, I thought my question was clear and reading it back it seems fine? I did try myself which is why I provided the first example that was working, I also provided the code that I couldn't get working, so hardly asking for "each and every character". Anyway, thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it and I have accepted your answer. Have a great weekend!